# How to read characteristic from Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to read characteristic from Bluetooth:

```
service uuid: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
characteristic uuid: 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

I have no idea of how to call those methods of `chr_get_value` and `chr_read`. I know the key is `gdbus`.

Comment: Can you perhaps post some code that you've attempted?  We need to get a better idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I compiled bluez5.47，you can see the source code in /bluez5.47/tools/gatt-service.c. I've attempted to call chr_read(struct characteristic *chr, DBusMessageIter *iter), but I don't know how to get the iter. my English is poor, hope you can understand.

Comment: Can you update your post with those details, and everything you tried to do?

Answer (score 2):

Service UUID you mentioned is GAP (Generic Access Profile) service UUID and the characteristics UUID (00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb) you are trying to read is Device name characteristics and returns the device name of the remote LE device.

bluez exposes all its functionalities over its DBus API. If you want to do this in DBus and C, you first need to understand DBus protocol and libdbus or any other DBus bindings API.

See doc/gatt-api.txt and test/example-gatt-client in bluez source directory for documentation and python example. test/example-gatt-client has good python example which helps you to understand how to scan, find and read characteristics of the device.

Otherwise if you know the BD_ADDR address(Bluetooth device address) of the device you want to connect, you can simply perform this task using bluez's gatttool tool.

For example if the address is 03:0F:45:65:43:FF and your device hci interface address is hci0 below sequence of commands reads 2a00 characteristics

```
[03:0F:45:65:43:FF][LE]> connect
Attempting to connect to 03:0F:45:65:43:FF
Connection successful

[03:0F:45:65:43:FF][LE]> primary
attr handle: 0x0001, end grp handle: 0x0005 uuid: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
attr handle: 0x0006, end grp handle: 0x0009 uuid: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
# lists all other primary services

[03:0F:45:65:43:FF][LE]> characteristics
handle: 0x0002, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0003, uuid: 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle: 0x0004, char properties: 0x02, char value handle: 0x0005, uuid: 00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
# lists all other characteristics as well

[03:0F:45:65:43:FF][LE]> char-read-uuid 2a00
handle: 0x0003   value: 4d 79 20 6e 61 6d 65
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't trying to connect remote device. It's seems difficult for me to express what I mean in English. I want to read my peripheral in Linux. I run the command "gatt-service" to register the "00001802-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" service and return OK, but i can't scan it in android app. If you can't understand what I mean, no reply necessary. ^_^

Comment: Ok. gatt-service just registers services. But to find your Linux peripheral from android app, you need to advertise your peripheral. See advtest tool in tools directory. You can also register your advertisement using DBus API, see test/example-advertisement python script.

Comment: I've ran the command "sudo hciconfig hci0 leadv" to advertise my peripheral. When I run "bluetoothctl" and "show", I can find the "00001802-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" uuid, but I can only scan "00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" and "00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" in android app. I'll see DBus API and advertise example. Thank you.